# Looking for specific solution for C# Regex pattern SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, regex, replace, find

I am modifying a C# app to loop through a bunch of SQL files and replacing a view name with its corresponding table name.

For example, a view named "Item" should be replaced with a table named "Item_mst".

I have a mapping file that the app looks at to determine which tables to replace and looks like this:

```
VIEWNAME1,TABLENAME1_MST
VIEWNAME2,TABLENAME2_MST
```

The problem is, there are a lot of scenarios to look for, I have described them below with an example SQL file.

```
Select 
    i.item <<Matches the Item table but is actually the name of the column, no replace
    ,dbo.item.u_m <<Matches the Item table with DBO., replace
    ,lot <<Matches the lot table but is actually the name of a column, no replace
    ,(Select top 1 cost from itemcost) as Cost <<itemcost is a table, replace
    ,(Select top 1 cost2 from dbo.itemcost) as Cost2 <<matches the itemcost table with dbo., replace
From 
    dbo.item i <<matches the item table with dbo.,replace
    cross join itemlot <<matches the itemlot table, replace
```

As you can see, there are many different scenarios, and I am having a hard time writing a regex/find and replace algorithm to catch every scenario reliably.

I am matching dbo.tablename and replacing those easy enough, it is the remaining scenarios I am having troubles with.  Are there any REGEX experts out there that have any ideas?

Here is a code snippet:

```
//Replace all matched views with table names
for (int j = 0; j < viewCount.Count(); j++)
{
    //replace for "."
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace(".", "XXXPERIODXXX");
    curFileText = Regex.Replace(curFileText, "dboXXXPERIODXXX" + ViewTables[0, j] + "XXXPERIODXXX", "dboXXXPERIODXXX" + ViewTables[1, j] + "XXXPERIODXXX", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace("XXXPERIODXXX", ".");

    //replace for "newline"
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "XXXNEWLINEXXX");
    curFileText = Regex.Replace(curFileText, ViewTables[0, j] + "XXXNEWLINEXXX", ViewTables[1, j] + "XXXNEWLINEXXX", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace("XXXNEWLINEXXX", System.Environment.NewLine);

    //Fix .column_mst spots
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace("dbo.", "XXXDBODOTXXX");
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace(".", "XXXDOTXXX");
    curFileText = Regex.Replace(curFileText, "XXXDOTXXX" + ViewTables[1, j], "XXXDOTXXX" + ViewTables[0, j], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace("XXXDOTXXX", ".");
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace("XXXDBODOTXXX", "dbo.");

    //replace for " "
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace(" ", "XXXSPACEXXX");
    curFileText = Regex.Replace(curFileText, "dbo." + ViewTables[0, j] + "XXXSPACEXXX", "dbo." + ViewTables[1, j] + "XXXSPACEXXX", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    curFileText = curFileText.Replace("XXXSPACEXXX", " ");
}
```

Comment: The description of what you want to do and its example are very complex. Please show an example of the input and the desired output so we can see **exactly** what you want. Then we may be able to interpret the explanation. Please also show what you have tried so far and explain why it is not doing what you want. Finally, what is the purpose of that "code snippet"? How does it relate to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not tackle the problem backwards? Depending on your RDBMS, you can use a query like `select table_name, view_definition from information_schema.views` to get a list of all view names and underlying SQL. Somewhere in that SQL for each view will be a `select ... from <table name>` statement for the views that are just based on a single table. Copy those results into Sublime or Notepad++ and use simple regex (replace `([\w\W]+)(\s+from\s+)(\S+)([\w\W]+)` with `$3`) to derive a list of view names associated with their underlying tables like this:
`vSomeView SomeTable
vOtherView OtherTable`

Once you have that, use regular expressions again to generate a `.Replace` chain to replace `^([^ ])( )(\w\W)$` with `.Replace("$1", "$3")`. Copy/paste that `.Replace` chain into the C# code you're using to perform this migration.